# wrong email / password message laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I use following code in my request(Laravel request validation) file

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'email.required' => 'Please enter email ',
        'email.email' => 'Please enter valid email ',
        'password.required' => 'Enter your password.',
    ];
}
```

I want to display validation errors if login credentials does not match with users table "wrong email/id or password", is it possible to write code for this here, or How should I write code in my controller for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
public function rules($data){
    $messages = [
        'email.required'        => 'Please enter email ',
        'email.exists'          => 'Email not registered',
        'email.email'           => 'Please enter valid email ',
        'password.required' => 'Enter your password.',
    ]; 

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'email'             =>'required|email|exists:users',
        'password'      =>'required'
    ], $messages);

    return $validator;
}
```

and in controller:

```
$validator = $this->rules($request->all());
if($validator->fails()){
   return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();   
}
else{
   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
     //login successful
   }
   else{
     return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors([
                'password' => 'Incorrect password!'
            ]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here should be the basic code-

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
```

Read more about it.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users